# Is it possible to texture bake a surface with lots of 'hair' geometry?

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, baking

I have a carpet here that I would like to use on a large scale, but the problem is that there is a lot of geometry and makes my workspace very slow:

[image]

Is it possible to use texture baking on this object to reduce the amount of geometry I need to work with whilst keeping the same level of detail?